# Createad webservice to display a list of objects database entytie

Tags: web-services, listobject

I need Create a "webservice" to display a list of objects by "entity framework database"
Gives erro:
EmployeeMenu, App_Code.z3zqdvha, Version = 0.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = Null because it is an interface.

code:

```
   public List<Meal> meals()
    {
       var md = (from c in db.Meal select new Meal { MealId=c.MealId,Name=c.Name }).ToList<Meal>();
        return md;
    }
 public List<Meal> getmeals()
    {
        CMSController cms = new CMSController();
        return cms.meals();
    }
```

Comment: I Resolved create a new class object : public class dishes
    {
        public int dishid { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
    }

Comment: New webservice is like:  public List<meats> meals()
    {
        List<meats> md = (from c in db.Meal select c).ToList().Select(item => new meats
        {
            meatid=item.MealId,
            description=item.Name
        }).OrderBy(s => s.meatid).ToList<meats>();
        return md;
    }